# iPhone App - NSArray Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

Hi I am learning how to code in Objective-C. I want to store the values of the textfields in my view in an array:

```
NSArray* answers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fluidIntake.text, sleepQuality.text, sleepQuantity.text, mentalRecovery.text, 
                          physicalRecovery.text, pretrainingEnergy.text, muscleSoreness.text, generalFatigue.text, nil];
```

Is this possible? If not is there any cleaner way to store multiple textfield values without having to assign them to an NSString variable..

Update:

Here is the function in my view controller:

```
-(IBAction)postData:(id)sender{ 
    diary = [[PersonalDiary alloc]init];

    NSArray* answers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fluidIntake.text, sleepQuality.text, sleepQuantity.text, mentalRecovery.text, 
                          physicalRecovery.text, pretrainingEnergy.text, muscleSoreness.text, generalFatigue.text, nil];


    [diary post:answers to:  @"http://www.abcdefg.com/test.php"];   
}
```

It is triggered upon a button press. It should store the 8 values input into the textfields in an NSArray and pass this to a function in my Model class which which at the minute attempts to print the first element in the array (i.e. the first textfield value):

```
-(void) post:(NSArray*) ans to:(NSString*) link{
    NSLog(@"%@", ans[0]); 
}
```

But it doesn't, it just prints : PersonalDiary[37114:207] __NSArrayI

Comment: You've posted much more code in the meantime; I've deleted my answer since it wasn't helpful anymore. The answers from @Joe and @Grady Player are very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly indexing the array in this method and using the wrong kind of string.

```
-(void) post:(NSArray*) ans to:(NSString*) link{
    NSString* a = "Hello";
    NSLog(@"%s%d", a, ans[0]); 
}
```

`ans[0]` will print the pointer address of your `NSArray` and not access your elements. To access your array you need to use `objectAtIndex:`. All NSString literals need to be prefixed with @. And when you print any kind of Objective-C object use %@ format. Also it is not safe to access objects of the array without checking the count first.

```
-(void) post:(NSArray*) ans to:(NSString*) link{
    NSString* a = @"Hello";
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", a, [ans objectAtIndex:0]); 
    //Or print entire array
    NSLog(@"%@", ans);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. Should work fine. Hard to say more without knowing more about what you're doing, but go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Using an NSArray is ok. You could also think of using an NSDictionary, which would allow to associate the text field value to the text field name:

```
 NSArray* values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fluidIntake.text ... nil];
 NSArray* keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fluidIntake" ... nil];
 NSDictionary* answers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
```

then you could retrieve the values like this:

```
 NSString* fluidIntake = [answers objectForKey:@"fluidIntake"];
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to do with these stored values. For example, are you expecting to read them from the collection during the lifetime of your program? And if so, how often? One thing about your current design, it works and is 'efficient', but it doesn't give you a maintanable way of retrieving all the values you are storing. Case in point, you want to update the physicalRecovery value later on in your program, how do you go about it?

In your current setup you would have to know that physicalRecovery is at index 4 in your array. While (maybe) ok for small collections of data this makes your program brittle and hard to maintain.

I would recommend as an alternative, that you use a NSDictionary to store your information instead. Its very similar to an array but you will be able to access your information via predefined keys - vastly improving maintainability. For example:

Somewhere in your .h file:

```
extern NSString * const KEY_FLUIDINTAKE;
extern NSString * const KEY_SLEEPQUALITY;
extern NSString * const KEY_SLEEPQUANTITY;
extern NSString * const KEY_MENTALRECOVERY;
extern NSString * const KEY_PHYSICALRECOVERY;
extern NSString * const KEY_PRETRAININGENERGY;
extern NSString * const KEY_MUSCLESORENESS;
extern NSString * const KEY_GENERALFATIGUE;
```

And in your .m file:

```
NSString * const KEY_FLUIDINTAKE = @"fluidIntake";
...
NSString * const KEY_GENERALFATIGUE = @"generalFatigue";
```

And in then you could store your values in a dictionary like so:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
    KEY_FLUIDINTAKE@, fluidIntake.text,
    ....
    KEY_GENERALFATIGUE, generalFatigue.text,
    nil];
```

And to access the values later on you would do this:

```
NSString * physicalRecoveryVal = (NSString *) [dict objectForKey: KEY_GENERALFATIGUE];
```

The main benefit of the dictionary being that later on you can add more data types, and never have to worry about remembering what index you will store them at in your array.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Once again, @Sergio and I post similar solutions! Haha.

Answer (score 1):

NO that is a bad idea, text will return `nil` if it isn't set, and that will terminate your array.
you should be using a dictionary really (for ease of debugging and future maintenance), and checking to see it the values of `someField.text==nil` and if it does insert `[NSNull null]` instead.

Comment: There are better options that inserting [NSNull null] to represent an 'empty' index and I would advise against it.

Comment: as would I, but if you have to represent a nil value, you can use NSNull. No key would be better in a dictionary, but if you are using the array constructor that takes a list of objects, and you want to indexes to be meaningful you can't just throw values in there that could be nil, as it will terminate the construction of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as this!

```
NSArray *array = @[textfield1.text, textfield2.text, textfield3.text];
```